# Using if statement to check individual value returned from a query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a seleect query which the return query is used in an if statement.

The query is correct, but the problem is becuase the query returns value from multiple rows it doesnt work.

I want to use the if statement to check individual values retrived by the query.

```
string security = "SELECT ProjectId FROM Project_List WHERE (ProfileId = (SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE (UserId = @UserId)))";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(security, myConnection);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);

    if (Request.QueryString["ProjectId"] == myCommand.ExecuteReader().ToString())
    {

    }
    else
    {
         Response.Redirect("projectlist.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. It should work because `ExecuteScalar` returns first column of the first row of the query. Other rows are ignored. What is the _real_ problem here?

Comment: just curious ... if you execute this `myCommand.ExecuteScalar` outside of the if statement what do you get when you check the data when debugging `data visualizer` also I would wrap that executing code around a try catch...

Comment: Do you have any exception, or the problem related with the code logic?

Comment: You updated `ExecuteScalar`  by `ExecuteReader`. So you first version of code was correct. Use `ExecuteScalar` and it will be work.

Comment: If `ProjectId` is a primary key and is returning multiple records, then you likely have a problem with your `Project_List` table.

Comment: @DrewKennedy, Why do you think so?

Comment: @DrewKennedy what you are saying makes absolutely no sense in the context of the OP's problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know if you have a `ProjectID` equals to the one passed in by the QueryString why don't you ask directly for it in the query text?

Given the text of your current sql command I suppose that a relationship exists between a `Project` stored in the `Project_List` table and a `User` stored in the `User_Profile` table expressed through the foreign key ProfileID.
If this is the case, then your query could be rewritten to

```
string security = @"SELECT pl.ProjectId 
                    FROM Project_List pl
                         INNER JOIN User_Profile up
                         ON up.ProfileID = pl.ProfileID 
                     WHERE up.UserId = @UserId 
                       AND pl.ProjectID = @pid";

using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(security, myConnection))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", 
                 Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ProjectID"]));

    // Now, if ExecuteScalar returns null then there are no 
    // Projects for that UserID
    object result = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result == null)
        // No projectid for the user profile
    else
        // You have one or more projectids for this user profile
}
```

Of course this assumes that you have already checked that the Request.QueryString contains the ProjectID entry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ExecuteScalar`, which, as it's name implies returns a single value, you have to use `ExecuteReader`:

```
SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   // grab next record selected
   int project_id = (int) reader[0];

   // do whatever you want with it
   if (Request.QueryString["ProjectId"] == project_id.ToString())
   {

   }
   else
   {
       Response.Redirect("projectlist.aspx");
   }
}
```

The `while` loop will traverse all records returned by the `SELECT` query and exit as soon as there no more records available.

Comment: thanks, those the if statement goes inside of outside the while?

Comment: @Musa If you place the `if` statement outside the `while` loop, then you will access only the *last* record fetched by the query. If you want to examine each and every record being fetched, then you have to do it *inside* the `while` loop. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: @Musa here is some good basic reading if you have questions about While loops and if conditionals [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm)